# Not every "tick" of scroll wheel is registering on physical mouse

Tags: mouse, macos

I have one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DHECXA) and use it on my MBP running macOS Sierra 10.12.1. When I scroll with the scroll wheel, the wheel gives little "ticks" as I scroll. Sometimes I want to only move the page a little bit, so I only scroll the wheel enough to feel one "tick". The problem is if I only scroll enough for one "tick", or scroll multiple "ticks" in succession but too slowly, the scroll doesn't register. If I scroll enough for multiple "ticks" but faster, I will almost always overshoot.

Is this a problem with my mouse? macOS? One of my settings?

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem with 2 different USB mice from 2 different manufacturers (SteelSeries and Razer). Both are somewhat expensive mice. The single clicks registers perfectly when connected to a PC running Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this issue also on sierra 10.12.1 with a wired Kensington mouse.  I just updated to 10.12.2 and even though there was no mention of anything changing related to mice mine seems to work as before, acknowledging each "tick".